# Relationship between dimension fields

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dimensional-modeling

I have a very simple dimenion model and ssas cube as below.

Now when I connect to cube using Power BI desktop, I want to create a simple bar chart showing number of customers in each region.

Basically count of CUST_CODE in each CUST_REGION. But I am not able to do it because PBI doesn't allow me to drag CUST_CODE to value.

When I just connect to the database directly to the tables and try to do the same thing, it works.

How to do it in the cube?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to write [MDX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/mdx/mdx-query-fundamentals-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017) query to get the desired data from cube.

You need to connect to SQL Server Analysis service database from PowerBI.

You can find it here :

[image: SSAS_DB_CONNECTOR]

Comment: Actually this is only a sample use case and using mdx for this works but users basically wants to do analysis using dimension attributes across various dimensions. They would have lots of other use cases and they don't know mdx.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking for the counts for each CUST_REGION, then you can add a DAX calculated column to the DIM_CUST table.  The following formula with return then count of CUST_CODE for the associated CUST_REGION.

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA(DIM_CUST[CUST_CODE]),
        ALLEXCEPT(DIM_CUST, DIM_CUST[CUST_REGION]
                 )
        )
```

Comment: He can't do it. His model is connected to OLAP cube, and in such cases PowerBi does not allow adding DAX measures.